# Xamarin.Forms "databind" individual values in Xaml for <x:Array type="{x:Type x:String}">

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a custom control with a property names "PredefinedOptions" of type IEnumerable. I'd like to populate this IEnumerable in Xaml.

This works:

```
<c:EditNameValueControl Label="{l10n:Translate Salutation}"
    <c:EditNameValueControl.PredefinedOptions>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>value A</x:String>
            <x:String>value B</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </c:EditNameValueControl.PredefinedOptions>
</c:EditNameValueControl>
```

However, how can I databind or call a function for each individual string?

I have translation resx files and a helper class (IMarkupExtension for string) to retrieve translations like so:

```
{l10n:Translate Salutation}
```

I'd like to set the individual values in the same manner (but don't know the syntax or if this is even possible).

For example:

```
<x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
    <x:String>{l10n:Translate ValueA}</x:String>
    <x:String>{l10n:Translate ValueB}</x:String>
</x:Array>
```

As a workaround, I am now doing this in code behind, but like to know if there is a solution anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Alright. Apparently x:Array is technically a MarkupExtension (ArrayExtension).

So, a colleague figured out that we might use the same syntax:

```
<x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
    <l10n:Translate>ValueA</l10n:Translate>
    <l10n:Translate>ValueB</l10n:Translate>
</x:Array>
```

And yes, that seems to work :)